# MenuStrip, obtener donde me encuentro

Tags: c#, windows-forms, menú

Estoy haciendo una aplicación de escritorio en c#, la misma tiene un `MenuStrip` y quisiera hacer un Log de Actividad, o sea anotar en una tabla información del usuario y que actividades hizo.

Tengo el método que se ejecuta cuando hace click en un item del `MenuStrip`.

```
private void menuStrip1_ItemClicked(object sender, ToolStripItemClickedEventArgs e)
{

    logact.graboLogActividad(e.ClickedItem.Text);
}
```

Pero solo me interesan los Items que son el último de una cadena.

A cuales me refiero:

Si el item tiene click definido, o sea se ejecuta un método me interesa.

Pero si el item despliega un conjunto de items no me interesa y quisiera saltearlo.

Por ahora: `logact.graboLogActividad(e.ClickedItem.Text);` guarda en la tabla todos los clicks que el usuario va haciendo.

Es evidente que tengo que preguntar usando `sender` y/o `e` en que situación me encuentro.

También quisiera obtener la cadena de items que termina con la ejecución de un método.

Por ejemplo:

si el método está en el árbol principal obtendría al hacer click sobre "Remate"
el texto "Remate" pues inmediatamente se ejecutaría el método asociado.

pero si el método esta luego de varios niveles, como ser Archivos/Clientes/Mantenimiento/Alta
quisiera obtener: dicha cadena y no solo "Altas" para poder diferenciarla de:
Archivos/Artículos/Mantenimiento/Alta

No quisiera grabar varias entradas en el Log de Actividad: "Archivos", "Artículos", "Mantenimiento" y "Alta", pues en realidad lo que se hizo fue un "Alta" todo lo otro fue la forma de llegar a través del Menú.

He observado que tengo 2 componentes del MenuStrip: `ToolStripDropDownItem` y `ToolStripItem`

PREGUNTAS:

A) Como identifico un item de tránsito de un item de ejecución.

B) Como obtengo la cadena de items que desemboca en un item de ejecución (sus parents).

Answer (score 0):

Luego de muchos intentos, no pude a través del:

```
    private void menuStrip1_ItemClicked(object sender, ToolStripItemClickedEventArgs e)
```

resolverlo, la gran ventaja que tendría hacerlo por aquí era ponerlo una única vez.

La solución que encontré, que implica que hay que ponerla en cada método llamado por el menuStrip1, es la siguiente:

```
    public partial class logact
    {
        private static string getOwner(object sender, string awAnterior)
        {
            string awRetorno = "";
            if (sender is ToolStripItem)
            {
                if (((ToolStripItem)sender).OwnerItem.Text != "")
                {
                    awRetorno = getOwner(((ToolStripItem)sender).Owner, awAnterior);
                }
                else
                {
                    awRetorno = awAnterior;
                }
            }
            else if (sender is ToolStripDropDownMenu)
            {
                awRetorno = getOwner((((ToolStripDropDownMenu)sender).OwnerItem).Owner, ((ToolStripDropDownMenu)sender).OwnerItem.Text + " - " + awAnterior);
            }
            else
            {
                awRetorno = awAnterior;
            }
            return awRetorno;
        }  

        public static void graboLogActividad(object sender)
        {
             string awOpcionMenu = getOwner(sender, ((ToolStripItem)sender).Text); 
             // aqui se graba en el archivo de "log de actividad"
        }
    }
```

Luego en cada método que se ejecuta en el click de las opciones del menu coloco:

```
graboLogActividad(sender);
```

El ahorro es importante comparado con lo que hacia anteriormente:

```
graboLogActividad("Mantenimiento - Impresoras - Tipo de Impresora - Impresora de DOS");
```